# Continuous surjection that is not an identification map

Tags: general-topology, continuity

EDIT: I had misunderstood the idea I was after so I edited this question to match the right idea.

We have $X=\{a,b,c\}$ and $Y=\{x,y\}$ and a free choice of the topologies on $X$ and $Y$. The purpose is to find a surjective function from $X$ to $Y$ that is not an identification map. So the function must induce a topology on $Y$, that is the identification topology, and then we must find another topology s.t. our function is continuous.

First I misunderstood the problem and thought that I should find a discountinuous surjection that would induce the identification topology. By definition there are no such functions. So there is some confusion in the comments.

I can answer this myself now but it's better to leave it here for others.

Comment: "The function and the topology on $X$ must induce a topology from $X$ to $Y$" what exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: @G.Chiusole  I think he means that $\tau_Y$ must be the smallest topology such that $f$ is open.

Comment: @BenW Or more usual: the largest topology so that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Yeah but he couldn't possibly mean that since the problem statement requires him to build a discontinuous function.

Comment: Induced topology here means the set $T_{Y}=\{V\in Y : f^{-1}(V)\in T_{X}\}$. BenW just answered the question very nicely. I don't understand the smallest/largest toppology ideas (yet).

Comment: @jonne_k  Well, that can't be right because then $f$ is continuous by definition.

Comment: @BenW Aha. Now I actually saw the problem also in your answer and this definition. No wonder I thought that it is impossible to build such a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the problem statement, when you say that $f$ induces at topology on $Y$, I take you to mean that $\tau_Y$ is the smallest topology containing $\{f(U):U\in\tau_X\}$.

Without loss of generality we assume $f:X\to Y$ is just $f(a)=f(b)=x$ and $f(c)=y$.  We want $\tau_X$ to be as small, but $\tau_Y$ to be large.  Let's focus on $\tau_Y$.  If $\{b\},\{c\}\in\tau_X$ then $\tau_Y$ is the discrete topology and hence as large as possible.  Now, $\tau_X$ can be as small as
$$
\tau_X=\{\emptyset,\{b\},\{c\},\{b,c\},X\}.
$$